# Error when rendering shared partial view as string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using this code I found to render the partial view as string.

```
    public string RenderPartialViewToString(string controlName, object viewData)
    {
        ViewPage viewPage = new ViewPage() { ViewContext = new ViewContext() };
        viewPage.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(viewData);
        viewPage.Controls.Add(viewPage.LoadControl(controlName));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                viewPage.RenderControl(tw);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I am feeding the function like this:

```
var s = RenderPartialViewToString("~/Views/Shared/_MyPartialView.cshtml", MyModel);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Type 'ASP._Page_Views_Shared__MyPartialView_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.
```

Anyone know how I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewPage` is for Web Forms views, not for Razor views.

I think you might be interested in the RazorEngine project: http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/